# i am trying to upgrade my 23.04 version to mantic minataour but this was showing an unresolvable error

Tags: 23.04

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: "*This was likely caused by...unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu*"

Comment: Identity the problem package in a ppa, ppa-purge the package, rerun sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, then try the release upgrade again.

Comment: If you are having problems figuring out which of the unofficial packages are causing the problem, edit your post and give details. Without that, all we can say is, good luck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: thanks all of you for showing your support. i think the problem is in the ppa packages now I have removed them.